# Is it possible to apply custom TFS policies to a part of a team project?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'd like to write a new custom policy for TFS 2010 and see that policy in VS.net 2010. I want the policy to block when a work item is associated with a check in and either:

- the code is in a particular folder
- the work item is tagged in a particular area

What I want to do is say that some parts of my team project are "high risk" and make people do more stuff (like testing, code review).

However, I want to only apply the policy to **some areas or source control folders** not the whole team project. Splitting the team project is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit a checkin to only apply to a specific source control folder, you can use the custom path policy: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2007/02/23/yet-more-team-foundation-server-power-tools.aspx